# STM32 SPI communication

Tags: c, stm32, spi, stm32f4discovery

I am trying SPI communication using `STM32F411VE`. I am getting some issues with SPI communication. I am following the transmit and receive from this particular code

http://www.handsonembedded.com/stm32f103-spl-tutorial-5/

I am using SPI4. an my Initialization of SPI is like this:

```
/* SPI4 init function */
void MX_SPI4_Init(void)
{

  hspi4.Instance = SPI4;
  hspi4.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi4.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi4.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi4.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi4.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi4.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi4.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8;
  hspi4.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi4.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi4.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi4.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}
```

Here is the code:

```
uint8_t SPISend(uint8_t data)
{
    SPI4->DR = data;
    while (!(SPI4->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
    while (!(SPI4->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
    while (!(SPI4->SR & SPI_SR_BSY));
    return(SPI4->DR);
}
```

I this particular `SPISend()` method the control never reaches to the end. It's stuck in the loop `while (!(SPI4->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));`.

My fuction call is like this:

```
void write8(char reg, unsigned char data)
{
    uint8_t retVal;
    enableChip;
    reg|=0x80;
    retVal = SPISend(reg);
    retVal = SPISend(data);
    disableChip;
}
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Probably `SPI4` should be declared with `volatile`. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know it can be changed by external causes.

Comment: `SPI4` is defined like this `#define SPI4    ((SPI_TypeDef *) SPI4_BASE)` in `stm32f411xe.h`

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, `SPI_CR1_SPE` and/or `SPI_CR1_SSI` should be enabled in `SPI4->CR1`. `HAL_SPI_Init()` doesn't set one or the other, but the HAL SPI transmit function does, you should do it yourself if you are using your own transmit code.

**UPDATE**

If you are enabling the `SPE` and `SSI` bits in `enableChip`, it'll be never called, because it's not a function call without the parentheses.

These two lines

```
SPI4->DR = data;
while (!(SPI4->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
```

are in the wrong order. You wait first for `TXE != 0`, which means that the transmitter queue is ready for more data, and then write the data.

The second line here

```
while (!(SPI4->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
while (!(SPI4->SR & SPI_SR_BSY));
```

will likely be an endless loop, because by the time `SPI_SR_RXNE` becomes `1`, or shortly thereafter, `SPI_SR_BSY` will change from `1` to `0`.

Comment: I have used this initialization  `SPI4->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSM;` `SPI4->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSI;`  `SPI4->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;` Is this the correct initialization